# Does presto support adding data sources dynamically?

Tags: presto

Does presto support adding data sources dynamically?
If don't, how can I achieve the purpose of adding new catalog by watching `.properties` files without restarting cluster?

Answer (score 2):

Currently Presto does not support addition or removal of catalog without server restart. There is a long running open issue about it which discusses the challenges related to implementing it https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/2445. I think the best you can do currently is to push the `.properties` changes to all nodes in the cluster and restart Presto daemons. You could invoke graceful shutdown on the worker nodes to minimize query failures and have something like monit automatically bring up Presto server if it is shutdown.

```
curl -v -XPUT --data '"SHUTTING_DOWN"' -H "Content-type: application/json" http://node-id:8081/v1/info/state
```

Restart of Presto daemon on the coordinator would still cause brief outage unless you have coordinator HA setup.